# Understand the Assembly Codes for Allowance Slot Calculation in Solady's ERC20.sol

Tags: evm

I'm exploring the ERC20.sol contract in the solady library (https://github.com/vectorized/solady/blob/main/src/tokens/ERC20.sol) and trying to understand a specific assembly code block used for calculating allowance storage slots. Here's the code in question:

````
/// @dev The allowance slot of (`owner`, `spender`) is given by:
/// ```
///     mstore(0x20, spender) // mstore at 32 in decimal
///     mstore(0x0c, _ALLOWANCE_SLOT_SEED) // mstore at 12 in decimal
///     mstore(0x00, owner) // mstore at 0 in decimal
///     let allowanceSlot := keccak256(0x0c, 0x34) // keccak256 starting at 12, covering 52 bytes
/// ```
uint256 private constant _ALLOWANCE_SLOT_SEED = 0x7f5e9f20
````

**Context:**

***Memory Storage in the Assembly Code:***

`mstore(0x20, spender)`: Stores the `spender` address at memory position `0x20` (32 in decimal).

`mstore(0x0c, _ALLOWANCE_SLOT_SEED)`: Stores the `_ALLOWANCE_SLOT_SEED` constant at memory position `0x0c` (12 in decimal).

`mstore(0x00, owner)`: Stores the `owner` address at memory position `0x00` (0 in decimal).

***Memory Layout:***

From `0x00 to 0x13(19)` (20 bytes): The `owner` address is stored.

From `0x0c(12) to 0x2b(43)` (32 bytes, starting at 12 in `owner` address) : `_ALLOWANCE_SLOT_SEED` is stored, overlapping with the `owner` address.

From `0x20(32) to 0x34 (52)` (20 bytes, starting at 32 into `_ALLOWANCE_SLOT_SEED`): The `spender` address is stored, overlapping with the end of `_ALLOWANCE_SLOT_SEED`.

***Hashing for the Allowance Slot:***

`let allowanceSlot := keccak256(0x0c, 0x34)`: This hashes the 52 bytes of memory starting from position 0x0c (12), covering the overlapping a 7-bytes slice of the `owner` address region, a total of `_ALLOWANCE_SLOT_SEED` region, and a total of the `spender` address region.

**Questions:**

Is it possible to set memory layout overlap at positions 12 and 32 to calculate the hash? How and why?

Thank you!

Comment: everything was clear up to your question. I don't understand the question.